# Color correct to counter low blue light

Tags: color, photo-editing, color-theory, color-spaces, video

Everytime I create a video,it looks good in a normal screen but considering half of the people have the low blue light effect enabled, I would like to balance somehow the colors of my videos to counter the effect of blue light, since otherwise my videos look orange.

Comment: In my phone the "corrected" screen look like orange overlay. So it's not lowering the amount of blue but rather adding more red. So to counter that I would put orange overlay on whole film and then correct it to look normal. Then remove the overlay. And make second video for people who don't use "blue light effect".

Comment: Unless you have some data to confirm that 50% of your viewers are using night mode at all times, I highly doubt that is actually the case, because I believe that on both mobile OS's it's off by default and even then it can be automated to turn on in low light situations. Then there's also PC users, who are less likely to have it or use it. But anyways, you can't really do it, because like @SZCZERZOKŁY said, it's basically an orange overlay that each user can adjust the intensity of. So no matter what you do to the source video, it's still getting that orange overlay.

Comment: The best you can do is make it look less orange, but it's only going to look weirder with night mode on and now it now looks weird without it too. So you're basically degrading the look for everyone. People who use the night mode get used to things being slightly orange tinted and they would turn it off if they cared about the color accuracy. It's literally about as easy to turn off as adjusting the volume. Even if you like hacked into every viewers device and managed to turn it off when they are watching your video, you would be working against the user, because they have it on for a reason.

Comment: "How can I fix it for everybody?" You can't. Give up now. If you fix it for one half you'll break it for the other. It's the same with every single image on the web. So few people know or care about colour accuracy that you are wasting your time. Get it right before it leaves you & everybody else will see it as they see every other image.. & they will be completely used to seeing them that way, they won't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Stop trying to do that.

There are some contradictions in your premises.

1. If a "normal" screen is ok to you this means that by definition, it fits into the "normal" category. Not extraordinary or abnormal. If "half" of the people do this or that, there is a chance that that is the "norm".

> have the low blue light effect enabled

2. I have no idea what is that. I really doubt half the people, even if that feature is installed on the phones, or tv screens or whatever, use it.

---

If someone wants to see the videos with a blue tint or orange tint (I still do not know what a blue light effect is), let them be. If they want to see the video on a dark screen, let them be. Just make your video look good enough on a "normal" screen... if that is possible in this era.

Adjust and calibrate your monitor. The more effort you put into this the better. You want to have your product in the centerline of a "norm" a "standard" that is what they are. Then you have room for some deviations on this centerline.